# Android option menu: change size of icon

Tags: android

I am using option menu, i want to increase the size of my icon...
means icon are too small... how can increase their width or height ....
or how remove space around icon.. i.e padding, margin etc...
i want a menu with icon at bottom... 
what i should do???

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.example.parentengagementtracking.BaseActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_base"
        android:theme="@style/MenuTheme" >

        <!-- android:theme="@style/Theme.FixedSize"> -->
    </activity>




<style name="MenuTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:panelFullBackground">@drawable/back11</item>
    <item name="android:padding">1dip</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">1dip</item>
</style>
```

public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_parent_home, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    Bundle objBundle; 
    Intent objIntent;
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {

    case R.id.menu_about_us:
        objIntent=null;
        objIntent = new Intent(BaseActivity.this,InfoActivity.class);
        objBundle=new Bundle();            
        objBundle.putString("source","BaseActivity");
        objIntent.putExtras(objBundle);
        finish();
        startActivity(objIntent);
        return true;

    case R.id.menu_profile:
        objIntent=null;
        objIntent = new Intent(BaseActivity.this,UserProfile.class);
        finish();
        startActivity(objIntent);
        return true;

    case R.id.menu_activity:
        objIntent=null;
        objIntent = new Intent(BaseActivity.this,ViewActivity.class);
        finish();
        startActivity(objIntent);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

```
<!--         android:icon="@drawable/homen" -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_profile"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/profile1"
    android:title="Profile"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_activity"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/reports"
    android:title="Reports"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_about_us"
    android:icon="@drawable/aboutusn"
    android:orderInCategory="4"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Aboutus"/>
```

how can i set padding, margin, width and height etc of icon..??

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to do. Could you upload a picture/let us know of an app that does what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your image should be 24*24 or 36*36.

Comment: currently 60*60 ?? then it should display a big icon ...  there is some space around the icon

Comment: See ,have the icons with same name and increasing sizes placed in ldpi ,mdpi ,hdpi  . try  greater size than 60*60 .may be 128*128 in ldpi , 256*256 in mdpi and 512*512 in hdpi

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this problem by using **"app:actionLayout"**.

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/menu1"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/custom_action_bar"  //this line will change icon
        android:visible="true"
        android:title="Menu 1"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Refer this docs [Custom menu icons](https://stablekernel.com/using-custom-views-as-menu-items/) to add listeners to custom menu.