# Design Bottom Navigation Like YouTube Android App

Tags: android, user-interface, bottomnavigationview, material-components-android

I almost done expect just 1 single thing. That is I don't want to show Title for the middle item in Bottom Navigation same as YouTube Android app does. But I could not able to span size of icon to cover full width as YouTube does. I even tried increasing vector asset size from 24dp to 48 dp but no effect. Would like to know how to fix it. ***Note***: I am not using floating button here. 

**This is what I am getting**
[image]

**This is how I want**

[image: This is How I want.]

Comment: You can use custom layout instead of using Bottom Navigation.

Comment: could you help with some details on it?

Comment: you can create just a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation and set your icons (some with text)

Comment: oh really. you think youtube has implemented this way?

Comment: I don't know how youTube done it but you can use this way , byw there is no swipe on youtube there are only clicks

Comment: because they are implemented using activity

Comment: ok my friend, here is your solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/50329772/12805923

Comment: app:actionLayout="@layout/custom_action_bar" this line?

Comment: Its not a floating button here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used some my common sense and split the whole bottom navigation view into

- BNV 1 - bottom navigation view 1
- Seperate Icon between two BNV
- BNV 2 - bottom navigation view 2

Here the diagram illustration

[image]

And now you have outline of what I am saying,
So just implement it

Have a nice Day!!

Comment: Good answer bro. But I was hoping like if there is something we can do with navigation only.

Comment: We can't do that, It was really an good idea. And If you want to da it , you have to waste many days to make your own custom class and blaw - blaw - blaw. So, I recommend it, To make it effective and fast. If like it please upvote

Comment: anoother way could be to just use floating button?

Comment: or You can make a whole BNV with five items and set icon and title of 3 item to be null or empty, And from programming site, set 3 itms to be enabled false and no click be allowed, And then using relative layut, You put a Floating button in the center of the parent. And it would be just like Youtube. Must try it. No regret. Thank you!!

Comment: Yes bro.. will gonna wait for some day if no better answer would come then definitely your answer is going to work.

Comment: then make my answer a tick

Comment: Obviously. If no answer is better than you.